# A paradox with probabilities

Tags: probability, soft-question

This is something I find funny that had been told to me during a dinner. There are different versions of this story:

### 1st - Binary matrix

Suppose you have a binary matrix with arbitrary values.

You know that for some arbitrary column $i$ (for example columns $3$), the probability that any element $j$ of that column is $1$ equals to $0.8$ and that for some arbitrary row $j$ (say $65$), the probability that any element $i$ of the row is $1$ is equal to $0.2$. what is the probability that the specific element at the intersection of this column and row is $1$?

### 2nd - Binary vector

You have a vector $x$ with $n$ components. You know that among components whose index is even there is $80\%$ of ones. And for components whose index is odd, there is $20\%$ of ones.

Now, you choose a random index, it is even. The probability that $x_i=1$ is $p(x_i=1|i=2k:k\in \mathbb N)=0.8$. 
Then, you observe the value of the index: $i=144$. The probability is $p(x_i=1|i=2k, i = 144:k\in \mathbb N) = p(x_i=1|i=144)$. And what is the value of $p(x_i=1|i=144)$ ? You can't tell.

So, here is the "paradox", maybe not exactly in the mathematical sense of paradox: there, you have a problem for which you know the answer only if you have partial information.

---

For the questions.

Where do the "probabilities" come from, since the matrix is arbitrary ? It depends on the meaning you give to probability. If you take it as a frequency, it makes sense. If you take it from some generative process, there are no generative process here.

The two conditions (on the matrix) are contradictory, both cannot hold. I disagree, take any binary $100\times 100$ matrix. Put 80 ones in column $i$ and $20$ ones in row $j$, and voila.

Comment: Needs clarification. When you speak of the probability that any element of that column equals 1, do you mean the probability of the entire column containing at least one 1, or probability of any individual element on that column being 1? If the matrix is filled with arbitrary values, from where do these probabilities rise? Also, what have you tried, and what do you reckon makes this a paradox?

Comment: Your two conditions are contradictory and cannot both hold.

Comment: I only read the first example, but it's like saying 'Suppose that the probability of an event is $0.8$, and suppose that the probability of same event is $0.2$. What is the probability of that event?' (which is why I did not read the second example).

Comment: Formally, you have for example $p(M_{ij}=1|i=3)$ and $p(M_{ij}=1|j=65)$, these are different events.